# Cannot seem to scrape a div class tag in Node.js

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping, cheerio

I'm new to node.js. My experience has been in Java and VBA. I'm trying to scrape a website for a friend and all is going well until I can't get what I’m after.

```
<div class="gwt-Label ADC2X2-c-q ADC2X2-b-nb ADC2X2-b-Zb">Phone: +4576 102900</div>
```

That tag just has a text. no attr or anything. Yet I cannot scrape it using cheerio.

```
if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var number = $('//tried everything here!').text();
    console.log(number);
```

this function I also played around with

```
    $('.ADC2X2').filter(function(i){
        console.log("Sdfs");
        console.log (i);
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

thanks all!

Comment: can you give more details ? can you write the exact tag ?

Comment: <div class="gwt-Label ADC2X2-c-q ADC2X2-b-nb ADC2X2-b-Zb">Phone: +4576 102900</div>

would be an example, how do I get the phone number?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I take answer from cheerio [documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

```
$(".gwt-Label").text();
```

if that's not working, maybe you have many frame in page.
Another possibility is page is renderer at client side, like angular pages, so element your search is not in server html, but only created after page load.
If that's true, you will to use a full browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and not only a dom traverser tool like cheerio.