# Node js requests and cheerio wait for page to fully load

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to scrape images off a page but the page returns a placeholder source attr if that page isn't fully loaded, (takes about 0.5 seconds to fully load) how would I make request wait?

tried doing

```
function findCommonMovies(movie, callback){

    request('http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q='+ movie +'&s=all', function (error, response, body) {
      if (error){
          return
      }else{
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var title = $(".result_text").first().text().split("(")[0].split(" ").join('')
          var commonMovies = []
          // var endurl = $("a[name=tt] .result_text a").attr("href")
          var endurl = $('a[name=tt]').parent().parent().find(".findSection .findList .findResult .result_text a").attr("href");


          request('http://www.imdb.com' + endurl, function (err, response, body) {

              if (err){
                  console.log(err)
              }else{

                  setInterval(function(){var $ = cheerio.load(body)}, 2000)

                  $(".rec_page .rec_item a img").each(function(){


                    var title = $(this).attr("title")
                    var image = $(this).attr("src")

                    commonMovies.push({title: title, image: image})
                  });
              }
              callback(commonMovies)
          });
      }
    });

}
findCommonMovies("Gotham", function(common){
  console.log(common)
})
```

Answer (score 11):

**Cheerio is not a web browser.** It's just a parser of HTML. Which means that the javascript functions which make the async requests are not being executed.

So. You can't do what you want unless you use something that acts as a web browser. [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) for example adds an API to a lot of web browsers.

You need to download Selenium client and keep running it as long as you want to keep making requests to sites with async content loading.

Also, you are going to need a wrapper based on the language you are using and the webdriver you want. The webdriver is used to add support for different web browsers.

I assume you are using NodeJS or something similar based on js so, [here you go.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

And be sure to check the [API.](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html)

Hope to be of some help.

You could also check [PhantomJS.](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

you can set timeout:

```
var options = {
    url : 'http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q='+ movie +'&s=all',
    timeout: 10000 //set waiting time till 10 minutes.
  }
  request(options, function(err, response, body){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
   //do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(function, millseconds to wait) will pause for how many seconds you want.
setTimeout(function(){var $ = cheerio.load(body)}, 2000)

Comment: You did the 2 second wait time? Did you try longer? Thats the only javascript function (besides setInterval) that allows you to pause. You could try declaring a function:   function cheerio (){ var $ = cheerio.load(body)} and then setTimeout(cheero, 2000); maybe its not liking the anonymous function

Comment: I'm pretty new to javascript so I could be wrong, but isn't the responce in request('http://www.imdb.com' + endurl, function (err, response, body) already delcared? I was thinking maybe there was a method that would wait

Comment: Can you edit and post more of your code? A request happens immediately. Heres an example xmlhttprequest: var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:80/orgstart", true);
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        if(this.responseText == '') { return;}   };//end onreadystate
 xhr1.send();

Comment: Okay so setInterval will continuously run just so you know. Inside the second request where the else starts.. do an if statement, depending on the type of data you are expecting from the response body, so if(response != datayouwant) { setTimeout( yourfunction, 2000)}  this will wait 2 seconds to load if the data you want isnt there. Do you know the type of data you want? To make a proper if statement

Comment: I do know what data I want, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3749900/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1 see where it says "People who liked this also liked... "? I'm trying to get the tv show's src to the image. if you scrolldown real quick you can see the placeholder it gives

Comment: Okay so if the src.length < 15 ? or == '' What does your scraper give you back ? Exactly. for src and for alt attributes

Comment: It retruns 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/small/film-293970583._CB514891998_.png' as the image, for all of them

Comment: Well, thats easy, then if the src equals that then run the setTimeout and load again, are you running one url at a time or multiple. Because otherwise this is a different issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072172/call-back-on-cheerio-node-js

Comment: Just one url.. What do you mean if the src equals the nopicture png, because wont it just produce the same thing?

Comment: Okay looks like I found an answer, but its not the one you are looking for http://phantomjs.org/ from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282011/cannot-seem-to-scrape-a-div-class-tag-in-node-js/34484206#34484206 I worked hard for this question of yours lol dealing with the server not having the data available until after page load. I have used Selenium with python but thats not js

Comment: I know thank you! also I have a lot of experience with Selenium in python, I know its really heavy weight application that's why I'm trying to find a way of not using it

Comment: "Its not a web browser Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating the resulting data structure. It does not interpret the result as a web browser does. Specifically, it does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript. If your use case requires any of this functionality, you should consider projects like PhantomJS or JSDom." from the cheerio docs. Have you used mechanize with python? I dont use version 2.7 python but I hear its awesome. Unfortunately I wish I had a better answer but I do think I answered your question

Comment: It's okay and I never used it, only used Selenium and request and beautiful soup for web scrapping

Comment: I know you are new to SO.Are you going to give me credit for answering your original question of setTimout() by hitting the checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me like your callback is located in the wrong place and there should be no need for any timer.  When `request()` calls its callback, the whole response is ready so no need for a timer.

Here's the code with the callback in the right place and also changed so that it has an error argument so the caller can propagate and detect errors:

```
function findCommonMovies(movie, callback){
    request('http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q='+ movie +'&s=all', function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
          callback(error);
          return;
      } else {
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var title = $(".result_text").first().text().split("(")[0].split(" ").join('')
          var commonMovies = [];
          // var endurl = $("a[name=tt] .result_text a").attr("href")
          var endurl = $('a[name=tt]').parent().parent().find(".findSection .findList .findResult .result_text a").attr("href");
          request('http://www.imdb.com' + endurl, function (err, response, body) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
                  callback(err); 
              } else {
                  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                  $(".rec_page .rec_item a img").each(function(){
                    var title = $(this).attr("title");
                    var image = $(this).attr("src");
                    commonMovies.push({title, image});
                  });
                  callback(null, commonMovies);
              }
          });
       }
    });
}

findCommonMovies("Gotham", function(err, common) {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);
  } else {
     console.log(common)
  }
});
```

Note: This will access ONLY the HTML markup served by the server for the URLs you request.  If those pages have content that is inserted by browser Javascript, that content will not be present in what you get here and no delay will make it appear.  That's because cheerio does not run browser Javascript, it JUST parses the HTML that the server originally sends.  To run browser Javascript, you need a more complete browser engine than cheerio provides such as PhantomJS that will actually run the page's Javascript.